# Handling Bitmaps in Windows 8/RT app

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-8, windows-rt

I have previously created a C# console application for manipulating Images. Now I'd like to port it over to a Windows 8/RT app. Unfortunately I can't seem to take advantage of following packages:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

Double-Clicking on the ".NET for Windows Store apps" reference, they do seem to still exist. 
Do I have to use some other classes for Image handling, or is it possible to get my old code working as is?

Comment: What are the key classes that you need?

Comment: I do almost eveything on Bitmaps, so this would be the major one. I also use classes like ColorMatrix, Graphics and Rectangle (for cropping).

Comment: It's not a real answer, but you might start from this namespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br243258.aspx and go from there

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently trying to wrap my head around that. For the time being, the WriteableBitmapEx library (http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com) does seem very promising for what I'm trying to accomplish. Still open to suggestions, though. ;-)

Comment: WriteableBitmap is an option that is easy to use but not very powerful. Direct2D is a little bit harder to start with, but you can do almost anything with it.

Comment: MSDN lists Windows 8 as Minimum supported Client for DirectX 2D. Will this work on Windows RT? Also for using DirectD2 one should be able to Code C++ if I'm right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing namespace is forbidden in Modern UI apps, there are third party libraries that implement part of the API ([like this one](http://www.moderncomponents.com/products/DrawingLibrary/)), but the best library for what you want (manipulate bitmaps) is [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/), your only other solutions will be Direct2D or, if you feel lucky, the Canvas element using HTML5 and JavaScript.